# matrix indexing to make new matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, indexing

I am trying to use imported data from a Scanning Transmission X-Ray Microscope raster scan in Matlab to create an intensity image in the form of an array. That is, the y-poisition is held constant and all x values are scanned and an intensity value is given for the relative (x,y) position. Then the next y value is taken, held constant and all x values are scanned, etc. The data is read as the column vectors into Matlab is as follows:

x = x-position ranging in values from 0-326 [104640x1 double]

y = y-position ranging in values from 0-319 [104640x1 double]

I = intensity at position (x,y) [104640x1 double]

I wish to create a a 326x319 array with entries corresponding to intensity vaules at the point (m0,n0)=(x0,y0)

I believe there is an easy way to do this using either matrix indexing or a for statement but I am relatively new to Matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
result = reshape(I,327,320);
```

Comment: Thanks Luis this is exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

reshape() function on co-ordinates with respect to intensity should work.